# Tomcat 8 application deploy when tomcat is launched as a service

Tags: tomcat

I have a problem to deploy my application. when I start Tomcat as a service,
`http://localhost:8080/` works fine but `http://localhost:8080/myappdirectory/` fails.
On another hand, if I shutdown service and start Tomcat from server.bat file, my application works. 
What can be the reason?
the error say: 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: how do you deploy your war file?

Comment: I have no War file. Can I use just sub-folder under ...webapps/ROOT/ ?

Answer (score 0):

for deploying a war file to get this address: `http://localhost:8080/myappdirectory/` you should rename the war file to `myappdirectory.war`

let me show it in an example:

1- start your tomcat

2- your war file name is: `project-name-1.0.war`, you must rename it to: `myappdirectory.war`

3- then copy it to your `webapps` directory which by default is: `{tomcat-directory}/webapps/`

or you can use tomcat gui for deploying it.

if there is no error in your war file (for example if you use EJB you must use TomEE not tomcat or at least add the components to your tomcat, otherwise your file won't deploy) tomcat automatically create a folder in that directory (`webapps`) which has the same name as your war file, after that you can see the result in the address you want

Comment: I have no war files. I have updated tomcat version from 7 to 8. Is it possible to continue old way? just using subfolders for .jsp files?